# AHK Gui button working as a toggle?

Tags: macros, autohotkey, gui, gaming

I have been searching for a while now on how to make a GUI button work as a toggle
 for a simple loop.

I'm stumped and need help. Here's my code.

```
#NoEnv

 #SingleInstance force

 #MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2

Gui, show, NoActivate w200 h200, TEST


Gui, Add, button, vbutton gbutton w80, button

return

button:

loop {

sendinput, c 

sleep, 700

}

return

escape::
exitapp
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop doesn't have an exit condition that would make it stop.

```
loop
{
    while sendingKeys
    {
        sendinput c
        sleep, 700
    }
    sleep 100
}
```

You would put this code to run immediately (instead of being in a button subroutine).  You would initialize sendingKeys prior to the loop to be the default for program startup.  The outer loop still doesn't have an exit condition, it just runs forever until Escape triggers an ExitApp event (which may work just fine in your case).

```
sendingKeys := False    ; make the user toggle first before loop turns on
```

In the button subroutine then you would just toggle the sendingKeys variable to go between true and false, which starts the inner loop or stops the inner loop when the variable changes state.

```
button:

    sendingKeys := not sendingKeys

return
```

When the inner loop isn't executing the outer loop just polls and keeps running until the inner loop starts executing again.